# Does communication between synthesizable FPGA modules increase I/O pin requirements?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, vivado

I've recently been unable to place a large design on an Alveo board due to excess usage of I/O pins, as indicated by the following Vivado message:

> IO Placement failed due to overutilization. This design contains 880 I/O ports
> while the target  device: xcu280 package: fsvh2892, contains only 746 available user I/O. (...)

I know I could simply reduce the number of external-facing ports from the design to reduce I/O usage, but I was wondering whether communication between the various modules from my block diagram could also be adding some pressure to I/O pin count. Is that possible?

Comment: Not if you're doing it right. But if you're working on one module in isolation, there are settings to turn off I/O pin allocation for what will turn out to be purely internal signals when you integrate it into the full design.

Comment: what?? I/O pin requirement is based on the number of I/O pins. Nothing else!

Comment: Note that ALL I/O exposed by the top level module becomes external I/O, even if you haven't added a pin constraint (the tool will assign a pin for you of its choosing). Not sure if this is what's catching you but I've seen this mistake before.

Comment: Intermodule communication does use on chip resources, but you'd get a different error message, I/O is limited by I/O slices. You might be able to multiplex some of your excess I/O, especially if it's non time critical, or only used for debug.

Comment: I figured out the root problem: I had the wrong top module selected during synthesis, so several internal signals, now exposed, ended up consuming a lot of I/O ports. Thanks to everyone for the insights, though.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible: IO utilization stems from using the IO slices in your designs, and if your cores don't use them, they won't be utilized.